# Change Power Schemes in UWP

Tags: uwp

Is is possible to change the power schemes via a UWP application?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Change Power Schemes in UWP

Currently, there is no such api that could manager Power Schemes within UWP platform, it is system level. If you do want this feature please feel free post your requirement with Windows Feed Back Hub App.